# Non-www Post URL on Jekyll leading to 404

Tags: .htaccess, web, http-status-code-404, jekyll, canonicalization

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I'm hosting a blog on Github Pages which is running on Jekyll. Canonicalization works fine on the index page (usabilityreport.de -> www.usabilityreport.de) whereas it doesn't on subpages. usabilityreport.de/user-experience should lead to [this page](http://www.usabilityreport.de/user-experience) but instead it results in a generic 404 page.

GitHub does not allow *.htaccess* files so I can't use *RewriteEngine On*. My research has only lead me to a canonicalization tag in the  which has no effect.

```
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ site.url }}{{ page.url | replace:'index.html',''}}">
```

The complete code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/JohannesBorchard/usabilityreport).

Answer (score 0):

`rel=canonical` link element indicates the preferred URL to search engines, it won't have any effect redirecting webpages.

As you are building your links with `{{ site.url }}` prefix, then make sure `site.url` contains your preferred website version, i.e., includes `www.` prefix.

In `_config.yml`:

```
   url: www.usabilityreport.de/
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I added the desired url to my _config.yml but it still wont redirect.

Comment: @JohannesBorchard the problem is not redirecting, but generating the link with the proper prefix

Comment: Just checked your page, it is working online: http://www.usabilityreport.de/user-experience. Locally it won't change anything because it is working with `localhost`.

Comment: I pushed it to GitHub right away and never tested it locally. For me it's still not working under http://usabilityreport.de/user-experience

Comment: You might be visiting a cached version, test again in a while and it should work.

Comment: I just contacted my domain service. There has been a problem with the name server entries. Thank you anyway for the help!

Comment: Could you please elaborate? You must share the correct answer if you're using this forum, please don't be mean :)